# MySQL Update inner Join with MAX Date

Tags: mysql, sql

In MYSQL 8.0 I have two tables with following structure:

```
Table1 :Child
ChildId | EnrolmentId | EnrolmentStatus

Table 2 : Enrolment
EnrolmentId | EnrolmentStatus | DateUpdated
```

I am trying to update a value of **EnromentStatus** in child table by joining in on Enrolment table using the TSQL below:

```
UPDATE child
INNER JOIN enrolment ON child.enrolmentid= enrolment.enrolmentid
SET child.EnrolmentStatus = enrolment.enrolmentstatus 
WHERE child.enrolmentid = enrolment.enrolmentid;
```

Problem is Enrolment has multiple entries for the child enrolment so I need to do MAX(DateUpdated) to get just a single record to update the status to latest status but I can't wrap my head around to just get one record.

Comment: Is it necessary to use inner join only? Can't you use nested queries?

Comment: I can't quite remember which but i think you could make use of a JOIN on the update based on a selection like "select top 1.... order by DateUpdated DESC" which would pick the most recent date. Apologies for vagueness, got a lot going on at work at the moment. Hope this helps.

Comment: @groovy_guy no inner join is not necessary so long as I can get the latest record  using nested query. I have tried this but  it doesn't like it either: UPDATE child AS c
  JOIN
    (SELECT MAX(lastUpdatedDateTime), ccs.enrolmentid, ccs.arrangementStartDate,ccs.arrangementEndDate,ccs.`status`
      FROM ccsenrolment ccs
      WHERE c.EnrolmentId = ccs.enrolmentID
    ) a 
SET 
   c.enrolmentstatus = a.status,
 c.enrolmentsStartDate = a.arrangementstartdate,
 c.enrolmentEndDate = a.arrangementenddate;

Comment: Please include sample data for each table. Your description suggests, to me at least, that your table structure may need tweaking. If you have multiple Enrolment rows per Child row it suggests to me that the EnrolmentId in Enrolment table should be the primary key and there should be a foreign key back to Child table. Sample data would help clarify this. Sorry if I am barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this,
It's just a simple nested query that updates all of the child's statuses in one go without using `INNER JOIN`.

```
UPDATE  child
    SET child.enrolmentstatus= (
        SELECT enrolment.enrolmentstatus
        FROM enrolmentstatus
        WHERE child.enrolmentid = enrolment.enrolmentid
        ORDER BY DateUpdated DESC
        LIMIT 1
    )
```

Comment: Worked great, I just had to add LIMIT 1 otherwise it complained about multiple rows in sub query.

Comment: @snowflakes74 yes let me update the limit in the query for others in case if someone finds it useful

Answer (score 1):

If your Enrolment table is tracking EnrolmentStatus over time then it would
appear that the current relationship between the two tables is the wrong way round.

```
CREATE TABLE Child (
    ChildId TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    EnrolmentStatus VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE EnrolmentStatusLog (
    EnrolmentStatusLogId TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ChildId TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    EnrolmentStatus VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    DateUpdated DATETIME NOT NULL
);
```

then the query proposed by @groovy_guy just needs the join to be changed

```
UPDATE  Child
    SET Child.EnrolmentStatus= (
        SELECT EnrolmentStatusLog.EnrolmentStatus
        FROM EnrolmentStatusLog
        WHERE Child.ChildId = EnrolmentStatusLog.ChildId
        ORDER BY DateUpdated DESC
        LIMIT 1
    );
```

If the above assumptions about structure are correct you could do away with this query by making your changes to Child.EnrolmentStatus directly and using a trigger to populate the EnrolmentStatusLog